# how to have grease pencil's noise modifier for 3d objects

Tags: 3d, 2d, blender, blender-2.67, blender-2.76

I did animation in CTA4, I imported it as Png sequence in blender, now I want to have same grease pencil render style for it such as noise modifier, and other effects. because I love the grease pencil modifiers and effects, so how can I do that.
please advice if anyone knows that.

I even created bump maps for the images using LAIGTER software, now it catches light in render view.
just noise modifier is needed for now.